# Next.js Warning por consola al intentar usar dentro de mi componente <Link> un componente <Image>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, warnings

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Next.js y estoy en el header actualmente, el logo de mi proyecto quiero que sea un enlace y que redirija a la página de inicio, éste es mi código:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from '../styles/Header.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
        <div className='contenedor'>
            <div className={styles.container_flex}>

                <div>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <Image 
                            src='/img/logo.svg' 
                            alt='ImagenLogo'
                            width={400}
                            height={100}  
                            className={styles.logo}
                        />
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <Link href='/'>Inicio</Link>
                    <Link href='/nosotros'>Nosotros</Link>
                    <Link href='/blog'>Blog</Link>
                    <Link href='/tienda'>Tienda</Link>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Al meter la imagen `Image` dentro del componente `<Link>` se produce este warning
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El logo en realidad funciona, quiero decir, haces click y te lleva al inicio correctamente, pero es molesto ver ese warning cada vez que recargo la página, ¿hay alguna forma de evitarlo?

He probado en mi código a meter el componente  dentro de un fragment, así:

```
<Link href='/'>
       <>
         <Image 
             src='/img/logo.svg' 
             alt='ImagenLogo'
             width={400}
             height={100}  
             className={styles.logo}
          />
       </>
</Link>
```

Pero aunque esto me quita el warning de la consola, la funcionalidad se pierde y ya no redirige a inicio (directamente no hace nada al pulsar el logo).

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues di con la solución resulta que Next.js al usar el componente Link y tener como hijo otro componente funcional, nos marca este warning, para corregir esto, simplemente tenemos que meter nuestro componente funcional dentro de la etiqueta `<a>` de esta forma el código en mi caso queda así y se soluciona el warning.

```
<Link href='/'>
    <a>
       <Image 
          src='/img/logo.svg' 
          alt='ImagenLogo'
          width={400}
          height={100}  
          className={styles.logo}
        />
     </a>                   
</Link>
```